# How to insert text in the backgroung of a View in Android Studio and Java

Tags: android, text, background, drawable

In Android Studio I need to insert text in a drawable, to use it as a background of a TextView.

In Android Studio I inserted, as a background, a rectangle around a TextView, as shown in the first picture and in the following code.
Now I would like to add some text in the background as shown in the second picture below.
How can I do ? Thank you.

[current and desidered output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpiZp.jpg)

```
**res\drawable\disegno.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
    <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#FFC107" />
    <padding android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
</shape>

**res\layout\activity_main.xml**
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/disegno"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Comment: In your case, you need to use EditText and not TextView. edittext make the background you have in the drawable folder.

Comment: @Buratino Apps, the result I need to get is indicated in the second figure I posted above [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpiZp.jpg). I want to insert text into the background image (a drawable). Using an EditText does not solve the problem. Anyway thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Edittext absolutely solves everything. You create an edittext as a background for it, assign your figure by id from the drawable folder, then specify a hint in which you write the text you need. And if you are talking about the inscription on top, this is also from the edittext section.

Comment: Yes, I have to insert the inscription on top. How can I do this from the edittext section ? Can you give me and example ? Thanks

Comment: I answered that you need a little lower

Answer (score 0):

Just change your background and add your text to the hint.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="148dp"
    android:hint="Enter your email"
    app:boxStrokeColor="#000000"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/inputTextField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```